# Export and Import DateObjects

Tags: export, import, date-and-time

I have a number of long lists of `DateObject`s paired with values.
An example data element looks like this:

[image]

It takes several hours of processing time to generate these lists and as I can reuse them, I want to save them so I can `Import` them as needed rather than recalculating them.

I tried exporting the data lists:

```
Export[".../Index model/sp.CSV", sp,"CSV"];
```

Upon then:

```
Import[".../Index model/sp.CSV","CSV"]
```

I get elements that look like the following:

```
{"DateObject[{1977, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, \"Instant\", \"Gregorian\", \
-5.]", 101.04}
```

Which does not give me an immediately computable `DateObject`.

I appreciate that I can derive a `DateObject` from this imported data, but that defeats some of the purpose in exporting the data in the first place.

Does someway exist so I can `Export` `DateObject`s that stay `DateObject`s on `Import`?

Comment: `ToExpression` can restore it after import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

dates = RandomDate[DateObject[List[2022], "Year"], 5] // Sort
```

[image]

```
Export["test.tsv", dates, "Text"]

(* "test.tsv" *)

dates2 = Import["test.tsv"] // ToExpression // Flatten;
```

They are identical,

```
dates === dates2

(* True *)
```